# How to map all .json URLs to a specific controller

Tags: java, spring

Currently my web.xml shows the following...

```
<!-- Spring Web MVC dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I'd like to do is limit all `.json` URLs to a specific controller.  To be honest I'm not entirely sure how DispatcherServlet in Spring works, so I'm not sure if this is on the right track or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DispatcherServlet follows the request to the right Spring controller. So, depending of  your web.xml, you can do this in your web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And create a Spring controller, with annotations for instance, like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/*.json")
public class TheController {

}
```

Some usefull resources:
http://blog.netapsys.fr/index.php/post/2008/04/13/Introduction-A-Spring-MVC
http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: Is it possible in the url-pattern to match everything except .jsp's?

Comment: I have never tried this for jsps, but the `mvc:resources` element tells Spring to not intercept certain types of file requests. You can try: `<mvc:resources mapping="/jsp/**" location="/jsp/" />`.

Comment: Like steve said, you should definitely be able to do this with mvc:resources if all of your jsps are in their own directory.  This will keep those request from being passed through Spring's DispatcherServlet.  If you don't want it to bypass the DispatcherServlet but instead want it to be routed to a specific Spring Controller, I don't think this is what you're looking for.